# Oracle: Creating a range on month between two dates

Tags: oracle11g

I have the below table: I also have a calendar table if needed.

```
ID    Start_dt          End_dt
 1      1/9/2016         3/10/2016
```

Expected Output:

```
ID    Start_dt      End_dt         Month   ActiveCustomerPerMonth
 1      1/9/16       3/10/2016    201601         1
 1      1/9/16       3/10/2016    201602         1
 1      1/9/16       3/10/2016    201603         0 (Not Active end of Month)
```

I need this as I'm working on a current query that will utilize a case statement to count if the customer was active for that month. If the member was active on the last day of the month, the member would be considred active for that month. But I need to be able to count for al months for that customer.

```
  CASE 
     WHEN LAST_DAY(x.END_DT) = x.END_DT
       THEN '1'
     WHEN  TO_CHAR(X.END_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') != '01/01/3000' 
       OR X.DISCHARGE_REASON IS NOT NULL 
        THEN '0'   
     WHEN X.FIRST_ASSGN_DT IS NULL
        THEN '0'      
   ELSE '1'
    END ActiveMemberForMonth
```

I'm new to Oracle and was reading about connect by but did not understand the process and not sure if this would be the proper place to use.

Comment: ?? Please explain the requirement in more detail. It seems you are given a start date and an end date, and you are trying to produce several rows, with a new "Month" value... but what are the rules? In your example the dates are from January to May 2016, but the months are from January to March. What's the business logic there?

Comment: @mathguy 
I've updated my question to reflect the correct dates. I'm trying to get a count of Active Members per month based on my case statement logic but need to identify if that member was active during that month. If the member was active at end of month that member is considered active for that month

Comment: Any ideas or feedback?

Comment: So if the end_date is March 31, is the customer active at the end of March? (I assume not - that must mean they closed their account on March 31, so at midnight they are no longer active, but your business requirement may be different.)

Comment: @mathguy The customer would be considered active.

Comment: I have the below join but it's incorrect.  RIGHT JOIN CALENDAR CAL ON (TRUNC(CAL.CALENDAR_DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(X.START_DT) AND CASE WHEN TRUNC(X.END_DT) = '31-DEC-9999' THEN SYSDATE ELSE X.END_DT END )

Comment: You shouldn't need joins for this assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
with
     test_data ( id, start_dt, end_dt ) as (
       select 1, to_date('1/9/2016' , 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('3/10/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                                                                       from dual union all
       select 2, to_date('1/23/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('5/31/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                                                                       from dual
     )
--  end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select id, start_dt, end_dt,
       to_char(add_months(trunc(start_dt, 'mm'), level - 1), 'yyyymm') as mth,
       case when end_dt < last_day(end_dt) 
             and level  = 1 + months_between(trunc(end_dt, 'mm'), trunc(start_dt, 'mm'))
            then 0 else 1 end as active_at_month_end
from   test_data
connect by level <= 1 +  months_between(trunc(end_dt, 'mm'), trunc(start_dt, 'mm'))
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by id, mth  --  optional
;

 ID START_DT   END_DT     MTH    ACTIVE_AT_MONTH_END
--- ---------- ---------- ------ -------------------
  1 2016-01-09 2016-03-10 201601                   1
  1 2016-01-09 2016-03-10 201602                   1
  1 2016-01-09 2016-03-10 201603                   0
  2 2016-01-23 2016-05-31 201601                   1
  2 2016-01-23 2016-05-31 201602                   1
  2 2016-01-23 2016-05-31 201603                   1
  2 2016-01-23 2016-05-31 201604                   1
  2 2016-01-23 2016-05-31 201605                   1

8 rows selected.
```

Comment: I'm not getting the correct results on me end. I have removed the case statement for now but below is my query. For example Id 5776 has a startDate of 1/15/2013 End date of 11/30/2016 and my returning results does not change.

Comment: WITH ActiveMemberData (CLT_CLT_PGMID ,StartDate,EndDate) AS (
 SELECT DISTINCT x.CLT_CLT_PGMID, TO_DATE(x.start_dt, 'DD/MM/YY') AS StartDate,TO_DATE(x.end_dt, 'DD/MM/YY') AS EndDate
FROM ROSALIND.LTIH_PROGRAM_HIST X
LEFT JOIN  CONTACTS D ON X.ID = D.ID  
WHERE 1=1
 AND ID = '5776'  )                                    
SELECT DISTINCT 
ID,
StartDate, 
EndDate                                               
FROM  ActiveMemberData
WHERE 1=1
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 +  MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(EndDate, 'MM'), TRUNC(StartDate, 'MM'))
  AND PRIOR ID = ID
  AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not getting the correct results"? What **are** you getting that is incorrect?

Comment: From a quick reading of your query (in the above comment) - you are not generating the months (I don't see where you are), so I am not sure what it is doing - even without the CASE expression for the flag. Then: is it possible in your table to have the same ID appear more than once? That would be a problem! You need a primary key (or a unique key) in the table for the "prior id = id" part.

Comment: ... or, absent a unique key, you could use "prior id = id and prior start_date = start_date" (assuming the same client doesn't have two different rows with the same start_date).